# No MySQL Service in Windows Services Manager

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL Workbench recently, and had a bunch of problems starting MySQL. After a lot of troubleshooting I realized the MySQL Services wasn't running.  Also I don't have a 'bin' folder in the MySQL directory. I've seen some other weirdness as well. I'm thinking that something may have gotten mangled during the install. Is that a realistic assumption? At this this point is it better to uninstall and then reinstall MySQL?  Or is there an easy fix for the MySQL Services not running problem?

Comment: "and had a bunch of problems starting MySQL" — Did you install MySQL in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My appreciation is as follows::

1. To be able to use mysql workbench, you have to download a program to run on localhost, these can be Xamp, Wamp, among others.[This is the interface of Xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCVq.png)
2. After installing any of these programs, you start the mysql service that appears in these programs.[Connection from Mysql to localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwcVv.png)
3. Once the service starts, open your mysql workbench and connect to the localhost.
4. Finally, create your tables and do your queries in the workbench or in the mysql provided by PhpMyAdmin.

I hope it will be a great help.

Comment: MySQL Workbench communicates with MySQL directly. You don’t need xamp to make Workbench work.